# ConvergenceWarning no método Lasso CV - O que fazer para solucionar o problema?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Alguém poderia me ajudar em relação a este erro?

> ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to
>   increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 3.5998713265016704,
>   tolerance: 2.032346947042441 tol, rng, random, positive)

```
Lasso = LassoCV(normalize=True, cv=cv1, max_iter=60000000)
```

Eu já aumentei o valor de `max_iter` do método como podem ver, mas estes *warnings* seguem acontecendo e acredito que isso possa interferir em meus resultados.

Alguém sabe alguma solução para isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O warning acontece pela não convergência da técnica. Isso pode acontecer dependendo dos dados.
Aplique um [`standard scaling`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) ao invés da `normalization`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)
```

E então usar o X_scaled nos seus experimentos (mas lembrar de alterar a normalização do Lasso para `normalize=False`.

Comment: Poderia me dar uma dica, como utilizar?

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Conseguiu resolver?